# How to use template tag to populate 'placeholder' on django form

Tags: python, css, django, forms, placeholder

I have an update form which updates a 'set' of content - I'd like for the 'set' to render almost exactly as the user expects to see it in the front end. So to render the title of the 'set' I'm trying to render it from the update form, placing the title in the 'update title' form as a placeholder.

**Forms.py**

```py
class SetEdit(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta():
        model = Set
        fields = ('title','tags',)

        widgets = {
        "title":forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'borderless textinputclass editable',
                                        'placeholder':'TITLE SHOULD GO HERE'}),
        "tags":forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass editable',
                                        'placeholder':'add tags here',}),
        }

        labels = {
            "title":None,
            "tags":None,

        }

        help_texts = {
            'title':None,
            'tags':None,
        }
```

Where it says 'title should go here' I would like to add context - `{{set.title}}` however, when I add that, it renders literally as "{{set.title}}"

`{{set.title}}` is available in my template when I render the form, but I can't get it to render as the placeholder text - I can only get it to render outside of the form and this isn't the behaviour that I want.

**Template.html**

```html
<form class="post-action" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
<h1 data-placeholder=' ' class='mb-3 editable'>{{set_edit.title}}{{set.title}}</h1>
```

Comment: I have tried to do this with Jquery and it breaks the CSRF token

Comment: I don't really understand why this is needed. The placeholder is shown only when the field is empty (so it's for showing an example to the user when creating an object), but when the field is being updated, it should contain the value that is being edited (not a placeholder, an actual value that can be selected/editied/removed by the user). If the `SetEdit` form is used to edit an existing `Set` instance, then you will automatically see the `title` filled in. Are you passing the instance to the form?

Comment: I solved this - in a really simple way in the end. After I initiate the form in the view, I manipulated the placeholder:

set_edit = SetEdit() #this is the form
set_edit.fields['title'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = set.title # the view had access to the context I needed.

Comment: that works but breaks every UI rule users are used to when editing objects in a form.